# NodeJS 502.3 CGI timeout

Tags: node.js

I have a application in nodejs that fetch requests from third party API and update data in my MySQL database.

```
exports.saveDeposits = async (req, res, next) => {
   const ep = await epicPayKeys.getKeys(); // It is a database request
   ep.map( async (key) => {
      ...
      // Some transactions here
      // fetch() request to third party API
      // .catch() which returns res.status(500).send('Error saveDeposits');
   }
   res.status(202).send('Save Deposits');
}
```

When I run it in my localhost, everything works just fine. I moved the project to production and when I run it, I got an error:

HTTP Error 502.3 - Bad Gateway

The operation timed out

```
    The CGI application did not return a valid set of HTTP errors.
    A server acting as a proxy or gateway was unable to process the request due to an error in a parent gateway.

This error occurs when a CGI application does not return a valid set of HTTP headers, or when a proxy or gateway was unable to send the request to a parent gateway. You may need to get a network trace or contact the proxy server administrator, if it is not a CGI problem.
```

Any idea how can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Could you include what the HTTP headers are?

Comment: I don't include any http header in the response. Just the res.status(202).send('Save Deposits')

Comment: A response has always a HTTP header. It gets added by the browser/framework and gives information about the contenttype of the response and more.

Comment: I believe it set the default NodeJS HTTP header response (text/html). I also think the issue os related to timeout. Because the application keep running for few minutes before returning the error.